# Is it possible to send message as page to friend of authorized user using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible for my Facebook app, with the authorization of the user, to send messages to the user's friends as a page? If so, how would one go about this? Would it be the [Page Call to Action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-call-to-action/) in the Graph API?

Thank you, I'm pretty new to the Facebook API.

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: @WizKid Ok, in my app, I allow the user to select friends of theirs that they want to invite. How can I then notify the user's selected friends? (Basically send them a unique link that'll take them to my app.)

Comment: Answered in the FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite